# GTK entry save last value before exiting

Tags: python, gtk, gtkentry

I'm writing a gtk app using python. The application uses a lot of gtk entry, that are empty when i start the program.

Is there a way to "save" the entry text when i close the application, and then restore them when i start the program again?

Comment: close as in stop the whole process. then you have to store the data somewhere a file or something like that.. upon reopening read and enter text in to entry widget.. i don't think there is a gtk or glib function which does this and all...

Comment: Gnome wiki has a page about it  - [Saving and Loading Window State.](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/SaveWindowState)